# Shared Resource in .Net Core 3.1 and Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core

After following [this](https://blog.codingmilitia.com/2019/04/24/aspnet-018-from-zero-to-overkill-internationalization) guide, and watching his [video on youtube](https://youtu.be/gov2ZVUSrYs?t=2100), specifically between 35:00 and 36:30, I still could not make a shared resource available for [my demo app](https://github.com/panosru/.net-rnd-i18n).

I have the class `Resources/SharedResource.cs`, but neither with `IHtmlLocalizer<SharedResource>` that I have in `Pages/Index.cshtml`, nor with `IStringLocalizer<SharedResource>` that I have in `Pages/Index.cshtml.cs` seems to be working.

In my `SharedReousrce.en-GB.resx` I have:

```xml
<data name="_COLOR_" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>colour</value>
</data>
```

And in my `SharedResource.en-US.resx` I have:

```xml
<data name="_COLOR_" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>color</value>
</data>
```

Normally I expected when I visit `https://localhost:5001/en-us` to see `color` on the view and in the console, and when visiting `https://localhost:5001/en-gb` to see `colour` on the view and in the console.

Currently, on the view, the key `_COLOR_` is being ignored and on the console, both the key `_COLOR_` from `SharedResource` but also the key `_WELCOME_` from index resource under `Resources/Pages/` are being ignored.

Any help would be great! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `SharedResources.cs` to a different location I cloned you project and moved it to the Localization folder and it worked.

Apparently they changed the way namespaces are calculated for resources in .net core 3.1. There is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17733) that explains the cause and a few other options for fixing this.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I moved the file under Localization folder as you suggested (I pushed to GitHub the change), but it still doesn't seem to work. For example, in the index page, I still get _COLOR_. Also in my terminal, the _localizer and _sharedLocalizer doesn't seem to translate the strings properly (index.cshtml.cs OnGet method). Would you be kind enough to let me know if I miss anything else? Thanks!

Comment: Ah, ok, I missed the location of the SharedResource resx file. Since the SharedResource.cs is under "Localization" folder, the same must apply under Resources folder, so Resources/Localization/SharedResource resx files and now it is working :)

Comment: I marked you answer as the correct one since it solved my issue! If you have some time though to help me out with Index.cshtml.cs line 30, I wonder why _localizer["_WELCOME_"] is not showing on the console... it works on the browser but not on the console. Thanks a ton!

Comment: From what I understood so far, is that while IViewLocalizer looks for Resources/Pages/Index.{locale}.resx the IStringLocalizer<IndexModel> looks for Resources/Pages/IndexModel.{locale}.resx

Comment: It looks like you are on the right track, I did a quick test by creating the `IndexModel.{locale}.resx` files and this fixes the console output. I would suggest that you move any values that need to be accessed from both the code and the page to the `SharedResource.resx` as they are in a way shared (or create another shared resource for model code) and keep the `Pages/Index{locale}.resx` for page only translations.

Comment: thanks a lot for taking the time to reply! What I ended up doing is ditch the IViewLocalizer completely and use IStringLocalizer for my texts and IHtmlLocalizer for strings that contain HTML tags, as you can see here: https://github.com/panosru/.net-rnd-i18n/blob/master/i18n/Pages/Index.cshtml. That way I do not end up with duplicate files or code, I have all the translation needed for Index page in IndexMode.{locale}.resx. I believe there is a better way to do it, but so far, this is what I got.